# Reading multiple parameters in for loop in shell

Tags: shell

I want to read partition and replicationfactor as parameter in my for loop  how can i do that? Instead of 2 and 3 i want to read from rf and partition  the corresponding values  for raw good and bad.

```
topics=(raw good bad)
rf=(4 6 8)
partition=(2 3 4)
for topic in ${topics[*]}
do
  bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --replication-factor 2 --partitions 3 --topic "$topic" --zookeeper $zk_hosts
done
```

Comment: Just to be clear, it would, e.g., `--replication-factor 4 --partitions 2 --topic raw`  and `--replication-factor 6 --partitions 3 --topic good`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a numeric loop:

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#topics[@]}; ++i )); do
    # whatever you want with the corresponding elements of each array, e.g. 
    echo "${topics[i]} ${rf[i]} ${partition[i]}"
done
```

The loop counter goes from 0 to the length of the array `topics`, so this assumes that each of the other arrays has the same number of elements.